# How to get next sequence in destination db and how to set this value into source db result in ssis ?

Tags: sql, ssis, sequence

I have  OLEDB Source and OLEDB Destination.I want to insert source data to destination, but when I inserting data to destination, I want to set ID column value as Destination Sequence (Next Value For). How I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with only an OLEDB Destination.

You have two options I can think of:

1. You can replace the OLEDB Destination with an OLEDB Command transformation and write SQL that will insert each row with the Sequence.
2. The method I would use would be have the OLEDB Command copy your data as is to either the destination table or a staging table, and then call a stored procedure that populates the final destination table with the Sequence.